# Unable to add a new ParseUser

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am using the following code for adding a new `ParseUser`:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("Rob");
user.setEmail("rob1989@gmail.com");
user.setPassword("robPass");
user.put("phone", "898989898");
user.saveInBackground();
```

After running this code nothing is reflected in my parse dashboard. I am not even getting any exception in the `Android Studio`.

However, when I run the following code, everything works just fine:

```
ParseObject item = new ParseObject("Item");
item.put("quantity", "dwad");
item.put("description", "dawda");
item.put("name", "fwafa");
item.saveInBackground();
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here in `ParseUser`? Is there anyway to check the dashboard from `Parse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clearly stated in the [official guide](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-signing-up), for `ParseUser`s you should use `ParseUser.signUpInBackground()`:

```
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
      // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
      // to figure out what went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

Once the user has signed up for the first time, you can use `save()` and `saveInBackground()` for any subsequent change in the user attributes. But first you have got to sign him up.

Comment: What if I don't want to use Signup?

Comment: BTW I have added `signUpInBackground ` in my application and still nothing is there. I used `saveInBackground` yesterday and it was working perfectly

Comment: "What if I don't want to use Signup?" - why would you? There's nothing different between calling save() and calling signUp(). signUp() does perform useful checks server-side, like rejecting sign ups with identical names and/or email.

Comment: "I used save yesterday and it was working perfectly" - it depends on your user. If it has already signed up, i.e. is already in the parse console online at parse.com, you **must** use save() (and signUp will not work). If it has not, then you **must** use signUp() (and save will not work).

Comment: Got it! But I can't see any new user after adding `SignUpInBackground` async call

Comment: Maybe you are getting some exception (e != null). Look at e.getMessage() (it is a string) to see what is happening.